# Cached Pages AJAX Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, manifest, jqtouch

Whenever a page is cached in both Firefox and Webkit, it appears to lose all ajax capabilities.

```
<html manifest=cache.manifest>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jqtouch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It will only retrieve pages that have been cached, no matter what. Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: Ajax Code:

```
    var http = false;
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
      http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
      http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 

  http.open("GET", "default.css", true);
http.setRequestHeader('CacheControl', "no-cache");
  http.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4) {
      alert('4(good):'+http.responseText);
    }
  }
  http.send(null);
```

Also using jquery $.ajax for the request. Neither work.
 JQuery:

```
    $.ajax({

    url: site_url,

    cache: false,

    dataType: 'html',

    data: ({uuid : devid}),

    success: function(response){
```

They always say successful, but only return data if the page is cached. Otherwise they return null "".

One last thing: I am requesting pages not on the manifest, because of a rather large server side backend. It would not be possible to have all pages in the manifest.

Basically, how would I access pages NOT on the manifest on same-site AJAX. Whenever I try currently it always return null.
return 03:11:41, even with no-cache, etc.

Comment: i don't think so , only server to server calls doesn't go second time , the client to server calls should work. are you doing pagelevel caching

Comment: can you give us more details like your ajax code calling backend.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true. If you explicitly request data from a page it re-downloads it for you. You can check this by opening Firebug, or Chrome's debug window and watch the browser make an http request.

Comment: how would I explicitly request it?

Comment: @precurson , what is calling the code , javascript or serverside code...if javascript you can open firebug , .net panel and see the results.

Comment: I don't get it, are you using jquery or are you writing your own XMLHTTP calls?

Comment: Usualy JQuery, I only used XMLHTTP to debug the problem since I am more familiar with it. So far I have been unsuccessful

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to get cache.manifest working for a while now and it kept giving me similar responses. I have a jquery mobile app that uses a web service to get it's data and wasn't working until I added the web service into the NETWORK section of my cache.manifest file

```
    CACHE MANIFEST
    # This is a comment.
# Cache manifest version 0.1.3.5
# If you change the version number in this comment,
# the cache manifest is no longer byte-for-byte
# identical.




NETWORK:
# All URLs that start with the following lines
# are whitelisted.

Service.svc

CACHE:
# Additional items to cache.

src/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
src/jstorage.min.js
src/jquery.numeric.js
src/jquery.format-1.1.min.js
assets/json2.min.js
assets/jquery.signaturepad.css
assets/jquery.signaturepad.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css
jquery.mobile-1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.0b2/images/ajax-loader.png
jquery.mobile-1.0b2/images/icon-search-black.png
jquery.mobile-1.0b2/images/icons-18-black.png
jquery.mobile-1.0b2/images/icons-18-white.png
jquery.mobile-1.0b2/images/icons-36-black.png
jquery.mobile-1.0b2/images/icons-36-white.png
src/link-1-3.js
src/events-1-3.js
src/custom-styles.css
Login.html
```

Comment: My AJAX URLs are in MVC format: `http://host/Controller/Action/` Specifying `/Action/` or `/Action` or `/Action/*` don't work. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

by default jquery's ajax functions will the data it receives (except for json & jsonp). You can tell the ajax call not to cache using the following:

```
$.ajax({
  cache: false
})
```

Comment: i never mentioned cache false in any of my code , but it always makes the calls.??any inputs

Comment: This doesn't work, as the problem is the application cache, not regular browser cache. Your suggestion addresses browser cache problems.

Answer (score 0):

The below code in IE makes a server call , as you are caching its not making subsequent calls...

```
if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
      http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```